# Links to other categories on my /listings/search page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following route:

```
resources :categories do 
  resources :subcategories
end
```

Which looks like this (from `rake routes`):

```
category GET    /categories/:id(.:format)   categories#show
```

And the following action:

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @categories = Category.all
    @campus = @categories[0]
    @community = @categories[1]
    @housing = @categories[2]
    @h2f = @categories[3]
    @free = @categories[4]
    @jobs = @categories[5]
    @talent = @categories[6]
    @personals = @categories[7]
    @sale = @categories[8]
    @services = @categories[9]
    @unboxing = @categories[10]
  end 

  def show
    @listings = Listing.where(category_id: params[:id]).order("created_at DESC")
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

I am trying to link to each category on the categories on my search page (path is `/listings/search`).

I have tried `<%= link_to 'Sale', @listing.categories_path(@sale) %>` and `<%= link_to 'Sale', category_path(@sale) %>` but nothing has worked.

Comment: It is not completely clear what you are looking for. What do your `Category` records look like?   Is `category_path(`X`)`, (where `X` is is the `id` in the `Category` model) not providing what you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(According to the link you posted) it looks like are trying to add these links on a page that is a `ListingsController` action, specifically `listings#search`, not to `category#show` as you showed.

I'm going to guess the route you're working on looks something like this:

### config/routes.rb

```
resources :listings do
  member do
    get 'search' => 'listings#search'
  end
end
```

### app/controllers/listings_controller.rb

```
class ListingsController
  def search
    @matching_listings = Listings.something
  end
end
```

When you visit the `listings` controller `search` route, *no other controller or controller action is going to be executed*. So the code you added to `CategoriesController#index` is not going to be run.

If you want to load the list of categories for other actions on the site such as `categories#show` or `listings#search`, you must either load them within the specific action method:

### app/controllers/listings_controller.rb

```
class ListingsController
  def search
    @matching_listings = Listings.something
    @categories = Categories.order(:name)
  end
end
```

### app/views/listings/search.html.erb

```
<ul class='categories'>
  <% @categories.each do |category| %>
    <li><%= link_to(category.name, category_path(category)) %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

However, this is very bad because you have to copy and paste this into a lot of different actions.

A better way to do this is to add a view helper method. Normally you would do this in the helper for the specific controller you want to add it to, and I'll give that example. But you could instead place it in your `ApplicationHelper` so that it would be available to templates in all controllers.

### app/helpers/listings_helper.rb

```
module ListingsHelper
  def all_categories
    Category.order(:name)
  end
end
```

### app/controllers/listings_controller.rb

```
class ListingsController
  def search
    @matching_listings = Listings.something
  end
end
```

### app/views/listings/search.html.erb

```
<ul class='categories'>
  <% all_categories.each do |category| %>
    <li><%= link_to(category.name, category_path(category)) %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Finally, I want to mention that the way you loaded the list of categories is *very bad*. You didn't specify a sort order, so the category records could be returned in any order. My examples are built so that they don't rely on the records being in a specific order, since I loop through the array of records. If you don't want them to be in alphabetical order, you should add a integer column to the `categories` table that you can sort by, so that you can control the order by changing those values.

Comment: Glad to hear it! Can you please [vote for my answer and mark the accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want a link to one of the categories (`Category#show`), then `<%=link_to 'Sale', category_path(@sale)%>` itself is correct, but you need to instantiate @sale. So suppose you want to list all categories and your category has an attribute `name`, you could do something like

```
<%@categories.each do |c|%>
  <%=link_to "#{c.name}", category_path(c)%>
<%end%>
```

If you just want the index page, it should be `categories_path` without any parameters.

Comment: What EJ2015 is providing is just what you want--except without the need to define all the instance variables.  Your example has a dangerous dependency in that you appear to already know the category IDs of the various categories.  The approach here removes that dependency.